# How would I "target" patches within a certain area?

Tags: netlogo

I have set up agents and nodes to represent people and stores and it is my intention that the agents will "target" the store in their "awareness" space with the highest value ("vulnerability"). I've largely coded what I have so far through trial and error however setting the turtle's target to the patch with the highest value within a 10 unit radius is a hurdle I can't get over. Currently they target the patch with the highest value regardless of its position in the world. Could somebody suggest what I might consider to achieve this please? I have pasted what I have written so far for reference.

Thanks.

```
breed [shoplifters a-shoplifter]
patches-own [vulnerability]
shoplifters-own [target
             awareness]


to setup
  clear-all
  setup-patches
  setup-turtles
  reset-ticks
end

to setup-patches
  setup-stores
end

to setup-stores
  ask n-of num-stores patches [ set pcolor lime ]  ;; create 'num-stores'         randomly
  ask patches [
    if pcolor = lime
    [ set vulnerability random 100
  ]
  ]
end


to setup-turtles
 setup-shoplifters
 setup-target
 end

to setup-shoplifters
   create-shoplifters num-shoplifters [  ;; create 'num-turtles' shoplifters     randomly
    set xcor random-xcor
    set ycor random-ycor
    set shape "person"
    set color red
  ]
end

to setup-awareness
  ask turtles [
  set awareness
  patches in-radius 10
  ]
end

to setup-target
  ask turtles [
    set target
    max-one-of patches [vulnerability]
  ]
end
```

Answer (score 3):

You are on the right track using `max-one-of`. At the moment, however, you are sending `patches` as the space to search through to look for the one with maximum vulnerability value, when you really want `patches in-radius 10`. So you could simply do this:

```
to setup-target
  ask turtles [
    set target max-one-of patches in-radius 10 [vulnerability]
  ]
end
```

However, this is going to be inefficient because NetLogo will have to first work out which are the patches within the radius. You have already asked the turtles to work this out and assign it to their variable 'awareness'. What you really want to do is therefore:

```
to setup-target
  ask shoplifters [
    set target max-one-of patches awareness [vulnerability]
  ]
end
```

Note that I also changed `ask turtles` to `ask shoplifters`. It is only shoplifters who have the attribute 'target' so you should only be asking them to calculate it. Same thing goes for 'awareness'. At the moment you don't have any other `breeds` so it's not causing an error, but it is good practice to use the `breed`, otherwise there is no point in creating it.